# C# Xamarin Android Steam API

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, steam

How would I work with steam API for Xamarin Android?
I have been trying to use the same dll files and such which I used for my Windows Desktop application but not working with Xamarin, any githubs or guide I can look at for C# Xamarin Steam API?

Trying to make it so the users can login with their steam account on the app

Thanks

Comment: can you tell us what steam is? is it the video game company that I am thinking about?

Comment: How do you not know what steam is xD http://store.steampowered.com/about/